# Arduino memcpy distorts serial output

Tags: arduino, memcpy

I am writing some code for an Arduino Uno that involves copying parts of arrays. The use of `memcpy` causes an entirely unrelated variable to occasionally appear corrupted in the serial output. Here is the code necessary to show the issue.

```
byte cchar[8][8];
byte fbold[16][16];
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  for (byte i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    memcpy(cchar + i*8, fbold + 16 * i , 8);
    Serial.println(i);
    Serial.println(i);
  }
  delay(500);
}
```

I believe that this should output the following on repeat:

```
1
1
2
2
3
3
4
4
5
5
6
6
7
7
```

but oddly, it is more like this: (taken directly from serial monitor)

```
0
0
1
1
2
2ff
4
5
4
4
5
5
6
6
7
7
0
0
1
1
2
2
3
3
4
4
5
5ff
7
07
7
```

With the `memcpy` command removed, it outputs as I would expect.
The logical conclusion would be that my `memcpy` is corrupting `i`.
But why though? `i` is supposedly never more than 7, `cchar` is 64 bytes long, and I'm only copying 8 bytes, right? So how would I be copying outside of `cchar`?

Comment: Without `Serial` are you getting stray `ff`?

Comment: @Buddy I don't understand. Without ```Serial``` how do I have any output at all? Also There are incorrect sometimes outputs other than ```ff```, sometimes ```w```'s, sometimes weird characters that are just displayed as squares. Also note how ```println``` fails to add a newline when it messes up. Weird, right?

Comment: @Buddy Now that I look at it again, it seems that those special characters don't even appear when pasted here, at least in chrome...

Comment: To learn more about the problem, if there's no output at all, then it might be an issue with `Serial` and `memcpy` together. If there are stray `ff` then it might be `memcpy` alone.

Comment: do you have 9600 baud set in Serial Monitor

Comment: @Juraj yes I do.

Comment: Well I fixed my problem, but I don't believe that my fix constitutes an answer, because I still have no idea why the above code worked as it did. Basically I changed the ```memcpy``` line to ```memcpy(&cchar [i][0], &fbold [i][0] , 8);``` I used the address-of operator instead of messy arithmetic to find my addresses. Still, the address for ```i``` was hundreds of bytes away from where the ```memcpy``` was taking place. This is still very odd to me.

Comment: short answer `memcpy(cchar + i, fbold + i, 8);`

Answer (score 0):

the problems is pointer arithmetic. `sizeof(*cchar)` is 8 so address of `cchar + 1` is 8 bytes after address of cchar

this works

```c
byte cchar[8][8];
byte fbold[16][16];

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 16; j++) {
      fbold[i][j] = j;
    }
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    memcpy(cchar + i, fbold + i, 8);
    for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
      Serial.print(cchar[i][j]);
      Serial.print(',');
    }
    Serial.println();
  }
}

void loop() {
}
```